# Namespace URL for industry standard XML format

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

I'm building a parser for Eagle schematic/board files for further processing, and generate the bulk of the code from an XSD file.

As this is not a standardized file format, there is no formal XSD file for this, and no canonical URI to refer to the format either.

What is the best practice for dealing with this? Should I use an URL within one of my own domains to avoid conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

### Namespace URI Selection

When selecting a namespace URI, consider the longevity of the commitment:

- **Temporary / throw-away**: For internal testing or quick answers on Stack Overflow, a URL based on a [**domain reserved for testing**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606) such as  `http://example.com/TOPIC` is
  sufficient.
- **Long term / permanent**: For lasting work shared publicly, you should use a namespace name that is controlled by the entity that
  will control the XSD.  If that entity will be you going forward, yes,
  you could use a URL based on one of your own domains.  However, if
  there is another organization that would be a fit to maintain the
  XSD, you should offer it to them and request a URI that is consistent
  with their policies, if any.  In your case, for example, you might
  contact CadSoft and suggest a URL based on
  `http://www.cadsoftusa.com/`.

Also keep in mind that [namespaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) may be any non-empty [URI](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), including [URNs](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2141.txt).  (Avoid relative URIs, however, as they are [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xppa).)